# Enable Amazon S3 bucket to Trigger Lambda function using SAM

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, aws-devops

I want to trigger a Lambda function whenever a file is uploaded to an Amazon S3 bucket with a certain prefix and suffix using SAM. Right now I'm using this code but it's giving error

"**The ARN is not well formed(Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidArgument**"

[image: Code]

[image]

**Edit:**

[image: 2nd way to do this]
This is working but it's not giving an option to add suffix or prefix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `NotificationConfiguration` you're simply using `!Ref HelloWorld` to reference your function, however, as [the documentation for `AWS::Serverless::Function`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-resource-function.html#sam-resource-function-return-values) states:

> When the logical ID of this resource is provided to the Ref intrinsic function, it returns the resource name of the underlying Lambda function.

If we look at [the documentation for the `LambdaConfiguration`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-bucket-notificationconfig-lambdaconfig.html) it states:

> The Amazon Resource Name (ARN) of the AWS Lambda function that Amazon S3 invokes when the specified event type occurs.

If you simply change the `!Ref HelloWorld` to `!GetAtt HelloWorld.Arn` it should pass in the correct value.

Beware however of the remark that is made on [the `NotificationConfiguration` documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-bucket-notificationconfig.html) that if you create the bucket at the same time as you're creating the notification configuration, you might end up with a circular dependency, since you also need to add a `AWS::Lamdba::Permission` (or use the `Events` of `AWS::Serverless::Function`) to allow S3 to invoke your lambda function.

Comment: I tried it changing to !GetAtt HelloWorld.Arn but got a different error.
Unable to validate the following destination configurations.

Comment: That might be because of missing permissions or the circular dependency I guess.

Comment: another way is to add trigger inside lambda properties, it was working without using any suffix and prefix. But here I want to add a trigger on suffix not on root level of s3.

Comment: If you add it using the lambda properties, it's also setting all the permissions automatically, so if you're setting the trigger on S3 by yourself, you also have to fix the permissions yourself

Comment: now I'm trying to add using lambda properties but how to add suffix and prefix information in it?

Comment: The same way you add the filter on the S3 notification, have a look at the documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-property-function-s3.html